# Diffrence between unique and inherited permission in sharepoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, permissions

What is the difference between unique and inherited permission in sharepoint 2016. and when and where we apply these permission

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an administrator or owner of a library, list, or survey, you can change permissions to let the right people access the data they need data while restricting others.

By default, all sites, lists, and libraries in a site collection inherit permissions settings from the site that is directly above them in the site hierarchy. This means a site inherits permissions from the root site of the site collection, and a sub site inherits permissions from its parent site. Folders, lists and documents inherit permissions from the site that contains them, and so on.

To assign unique permissions to a list, library, or survey, you have to first break permissions inheritance, then assign unique permissions. You can do all of this on the Permissions page.

NOTE: When a user shares a document or other individual item, inheritance is automatically broken for that item. Inherited permissions are copied to the item, and permissions for the users with whom the item was shared are added. But if changes in permissions are made to the parent item, those changes are not be applied to the item.

[Edit permissions for a list or library](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Edit-permissions-for-a-list-or-library-02D770F3-59EB-4910-A608-5F84CC297782?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

`Unique permission` - If you want users to have different level of access on certain sections of your portal, then you assign unique permission.

For example, a feedback section.

In your site, there is a functionality to provide feedback. So all users should be able to do that. To do this, you will provide all users `Contribute` permission on the `Feedback` list. But for other sections of the portal, you provide them with just `read` permission.

Comment: However if the parent folder is shared with user X via link sharing then user X gets access to all subfolders irrespective of whether subfolder inheritence was broken. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

**Inherited Permissions:** The item inherits permissions from its Parent. For example, List inherits from Site.

*Groups A1,A2,A3 have access to SharePoint Site, the same groups have access to List also.*

You can use this when all the site objects should have same Permissions.

**Unique Permissions:** The item have different permissions from its Parent. For example,List/Item have different Permissions from Site.

*Groups A1, A2, A3 have access to SharePoint site, But only group A1 has access to specific list.*

You can give unique permissions when you want to permit only certain set of users  to access the object. Unique permissions can be given at below levels
Site,List/Library,Folder,File,List Item.

Navigate to Permission settings page and click on stop inheriting permissions to give unique permissions.